# How to get field level help through wire in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

```
<lightning-helptext class="customIcon" content={helpText}></lightning-helptext>
```

How to fetch help text of a specific field in JS as we do in apex/VF using

```
$ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.Fields.Sale_Role__c.inlineHelpText (for e.g.).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all info about a object and its fields, child-relationships, named-fields etc through `getObjectInfo` wire service.

Below is example:

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

export default class Example extends LightningElement {
    @track fieldsInfo;
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    getAccountInfo(result) {
        if (result.data)
            this.fieldsInfo = result.data.fields;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={fieldsInfo}>
        Active help text - {fieldsInfo.Active__c.inlineHelpText}
    </template>
</template>
```